# Phonegap 1.1 / iOS5 Plugin Not Firing

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I'm trying to write a plugin for the iOS5 Phonegap stack using 1.1 I've tried every tutorial I can find including the one on the Phonegap wiki exactly as outlined [there](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753496/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS). Each time, when I try to execute the plugin from my HTML file, nothing happens at all and I see the following error in my debug console:

```
2011-10-31 21:01:09.761 TestApp[65870:13403] Ignoring gap command with incorrect sessionKey; expecting: -684243575 received: (null)
2011-10-31 21:01:09.761 TestApp[65870:13403] Complete call: gap://ready
```

This could be purely coincidental, but if I comment out the Javascript call to my plugin, that error isn't present in my console, so it must be somewhat related even if only remotely.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me most likely to be your PhoneGap.plist being incorrectly setup, give it another look.

If that isn't the issue, try testing your plugin by using the following form in your javascript.

```
PhoneGap.exec("ClassName.methodName", parameter1,parameter2);
```

Where ClassName.methodName is the Objective C ClassName and your method is something of this form

```
-(void)methodName:(NSMutableArray*)paramArray withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options
{
 NSLog(@"inside plugin!");
 //objective c Plugin code
}
```

When you do this, do you still get that error message?